# How can I ensure that a workflow is triggers email notification only after user clicks OK and not when the edit properties is clicked

Tags: sharepoint, workflowservice

I have a custom workflow built using SP DEsigner and the SP sites is created using wss 3.0. I have a customer column and values associated with it which is checked for teh workflow to trigger. Example: 
When the status = SME Review, an email shoudl trigger to the assigned to person with a message to take some action on the file. However when a user edits the properties, and if the file is already in SME REview and assigned to someone, it triggers an email before Ok is clicked.

This should not happen, becuase the file is bieng edited to change it to Content Review and will eb assigned to a new person. So the notficaition is going to the SME rather than the content reviewer. I am unable to stop this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On which position do you edit the element or is it a document?

- When you edit the listelement in Data Grid View the changes you make in a field are instantly saved when you are changing the field.
- If you are using the EditForm than it would submit the changed values only by clicking the okay buton.

Please put some more details to describe your Problem.